# Does JW Player support h.265?

Tags: video, jwplayer, encoder

Get the following error when trying to play video encoded with h.265

provider.hlsjs.js:10 Hlsjs shutdown Media Error: no level with compatible codecs found in manifest Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JW Player does not support anything. JW Player is just a wrapper around the browsers  media capabilities.

The only browsers that support h.265 are Edge and Safari. Chrome and Firefox will not be adding support.